# socket closed exception occurs in an infinite loop

Tags: java, sockets, server-side

I'm supposed to write a program that take some .class files as service and they should be loaded and do the service. I'm have done it using socket programming but since I have made it multi-threaded so services can be used by any number of clients, i'm getting socket closed exception which occurs in an infinite while loop after each client thread is done. Even with one client i still get this exception. the only time that i do not get exception is when there is no class to load which i use break. I've tried to find the problem and searched a lot but I couldn't find anything.
//this is main class for server side

```
    package reg.main;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.*;

    public class Application{
        private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

        public static void main(String[] args){
             while(true){
                InputStream input = null;
                Properties prop = new Properties();

                try{
                String filename = "config.properties";
                input = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                if(input == null){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                }
                prop.load(input);
                }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    System.out.println("properties file does not exist.");
                }
                try{
                    String port = prop.getProperty("port");
                    int portNo = Integer.parseInt(port);
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
                    LOGGER.debug("Server is listening... on port "  + portNo);

                    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                    service.execute(new Server(serverSocket.accept()));

                    serverSocket.close();
                    service.shutdown();

                }catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not close socket");
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }

        }

    }

// this is server side code

    package reg.main;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import reg.entity.*;
    import reg.utility.*;
    import reg.service.*;
    import reg.dao.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class Server implements Runnable{
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Server.class);
        private Socket clientSocket;

        public Server(Socket clientSocket){
            LOGGER.debug("Connection is Established.");
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        public void run(){
            ObjectOutputStream outToClient = null;
            ObjectInputStream inFromClient = null;

            try{
                outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                LOGGER.error("There is a problem in reading or writing.");
            }
            while(true){
                try{
                    String userOption =(String)inFromClient.readObject();//while printing stack trace, it says there is something wrong with this line. i don't know why!
                    System.out.println(userOption);
                    userOption = DataEditor.editOptionInputInfo(userOption); //this is a custom method 
                    Map<String,Service> mapper=    CustomClassLoader.loadClass();    //in class loader .class files will be loaded and an object of each of them will be sent in a map
                    if(mapper == null){
                        LOGGER.debug("no class file found to be loaded.");
                        clientSocket.close();
                        break;
                    }

                    List<String> classNames = CustomClassLoader.getClassNames();
                    boolean ckeckedUserOption = Validation.validUserOption(classNames,userOption);

                        if(ckeckedUserOption == false){
                            LOGGER.error("client has entered the wrong option.");
                        }

                        System.out.println(userOption + "in server class------------- before loading class");
                        Service service = mapper.get(userOption);
                        List<String> parameters = service.getRequiredParameters();
                        if(parameters.size() == 0){
                            LOGGER.debug("There is a problem with loaded classes.");
                        }

                        outToClient.writeObject(parameters);
                        LOGGER.debug("required parameters was sent to client.");
                        List<String>info = (List<String>)inFromClient.readObject();
                        LOGGER.debug("Information from client has been sent.");

                        if(info.size() == 0){
                            LOGGER.error("client has not put information. Try again.");
                            System.exit(2);
                        } 

                        String result = service.doOperation(info);
                        outToClient.writeObject(result);
                        LOGGER.debug("Result of required service was sent to client.");

                        inFromClient.close();
                        outToClient.close();
                        //clientSocket.close();

                }catch(IOException ex){
                    LOGGER.error("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                        + " or listening for a connection");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                    LOGGER.error("class was not found.");
                }
            }   
        }
    }
// this is client side

package reg.main;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

//Client class

    public class Client{
        private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Client.class);

        public static void main(String[] args){


            Socket clientSocket = null; 
            String userOption;

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            Properties prop = new Properties();

            try{
                String filename = "config.properties";
                inputStream = Client.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                if(inputStream == null){
                   System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                }
                prop.load(inputStream);
                }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    System.out.println("properties file does not exist.");
                }
            try{
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Do you want to sign in or login? put the file name in:");
                String path = input.next();
                LOGGER.debug("User entered " + path + " as the service option.");
                String port = prop.getProperty("port");
                int portNo = Integer.parseInt(port);
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                userOption = reader.readLine();

                clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.121.114", portNo);
                System.out.println("client is connected to the server.");

                ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                outToServer.writeObject(userOption);
                LOGGER.debug("sent the user option to server ==> " + userOption);

                List<String> listOfparams =(List<String>)inFromServer.readObject();
                LOGGER.debug("List of Requierements in Client " + listOfparams);
                List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String param : listOfparams){
                    System.out.println("Enter your " + param + ": ");
                    info.add(input.next());
                }
                outToServer.writeObject(info);
                String result = (String)inFromServer.readObject();
                LOGGER.debug("The result of required service: " + result);
                System.out.println(clientSocket.isClosed());

                inFromServer.close();
                outToServer.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Don't know about host ");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e){
                LOGGER.error("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host or there is no service for loading");
                System.exit(1);
            }
              catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                 LOGGER.error("class does not found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I appreciate any help. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` in catch

```
            try{
                String filename = "config.properties";
                input = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                if(input == null){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                }
                prop.load(input);
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("properties file does not exist.");
                break; // this make program to go out of the loop
            }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but break just stopped the loop and it did not solve the exception...

Comment: use return; instead